# Unresolved reference: drawable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

when a new project is created in 'Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2' the error 'Unresolved reference: drawable' exists:

```
@Composable
fun JetpackCompose() {
    Card {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Column(Modifier.clickable {  expanded = !expanded} ) {
            val image = painterResource(id = 
                R.drawable.jetpack_compose)
            Image(painter = image, contentDescription = null)
            AnimatedVisibility(expanded) {
                Text(
                    text = "Jetpack Compose",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error doesn't exist when the code above is pasted into a MainActivity.kt file of an existing project.

This problem started after a project created by an older version of Android Studio was opened in the newer Android Studio Chipmunk.  When the older project was opened different version of Gradle was being downloaded from the internet and installed, but I cancelled the process and deleted the old project, since reading using an incorrect version of Gradle in Android Studio can cause problems.

The imports match in both project except FunWithLayoutsTheme is ComposeArticleTheme in the other project:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.R
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.funwithlayouts.ui.theme.FunWithLayoutsTheme
```

All files and all the 'Gradle Scripts' files match in both projects. gradle-wrapper.properties file in both projects:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle- 
    7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Tried:

1. Grade Sync, Invalidate caches and restart, Clean the project and rebuild before doing 2 below.
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio checking all checkboxes during the process.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: What are your class imports?

Comment: If not, imports above, how to get class imports?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.R
```

to

```
import yourPackege.R
```

Comment: commented out //import androidx.compose.runtime.R

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Commented out //import androidx.compose.runtime.R, added import com.example.funwithlayouts.R, but it's an unused import and doesn't fix the error.  Please any other suggestion?

Comment: @KeithGarbutt why did you accept this answer if it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Comment out both the R imports or any one of the R imports if you have only one.
I don't know why but it worked for me.